# Pixel-wise colours change in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, colors, pixel

I change some the pixel colors ( the pixel who are in the vector `row_first`) to green,but the image changes this pixel values, but all the image is red,my original image `img_crop` is `double rgb`.

My code is below:

```
 for j=1:size(img_crop,2)%column
       img_crop(row_first(1,j),j,1)=0;
       img_crop(row_first(1,j),j,2)=1;
       img_crop(row_first(1,j),j,3)=0;
 end
```

Row_first is a vector that has in the first line the rowsindex,  per column for the  pixels in the image_crop that I want toc hange to green.

Basically I want to find the first maximum ( that has the highest row value, and then I want to find the next minimum value before this),and then the minimum that corresponds to my condition ( not important),and then paint the first minimum pixel [image]

This is the code I wrote shown below

```
for x = 1:size(img_gauss,2) 

%   for y=1:size(img_gauss,1)
    % Make a row wise intensity distribution graphic for each column starting
    %from the first row to the last because findpeaks will  assigned the
    %indices in that order, and then select the last
    %max will correspond to the far adventtitia

    %Find the peaks,local maximum for each column and assignment to the
    %respective column

    [z,local_min] = findpeaks(-img_gauss(1:size(img_gauss,1),x));%local min
    % Verify if this local minimum pixels are possible candidates for
    % lumen:
    for w=1:size(local_min,1)%rows
        if (mean_pixel(local_min(w,1),x)<0.0004705 && std_pixel(local_min(w,1),x)<0.0017)
            lumen_local(w,x)=local_min(w,1); 

        else
            nao_lumen(w,x)=local_min(w,1);
        end
    end

    % coordinates of the local maximum values
    [g,local_max]=findpeaks(img_gauss(1:size(img_gauss,1),x));%local max

    local_max(:,x)=local_max(:,1);

    % Assignm each maximum and minimum position  to the respective column,
    %per iteration, and sort both in a descendent way
    max_column(1:size(local_max,1),x)=sort(local_max(1:size(local_max,1),x),'descend');
    min_column(1:size(lumen_local,1),x)=sort(lumen_local(1:size(lumen_local,1),x),'descend');


% BW = imregionalmin(img_gauss(y,x)); 

  end
% end

for q=1:size(img_gauss,2)
    for a=1:size(img_gauss,1)
        if mean_pixel(a,q)<0.0004705 && std_pixel(a,q)<0.0017 
            img_gauss(a,q)=1;%white
        else 
            img_gauss(a,q)=0;%black
        end
    end
end      
figure(9), imshow(img_gauss);
img_close=imclose(img_gauss,ones(20,20));
figure(10),imshow(img_close);

  % The first maximum with the highest row number correspond to the
  % adventícia,so now the first minimum  before correspond to the lumen

  for i=1:size(max_column,2)
      max_adve(:,i)=max_column(1,i);% [row col] of the the first adventicia pixel
      row_first(1,i)= min_column(find(min_column(:,i)<max_adve(:,i),1),i);
  end

   % Put the lumen pixels at green
   for j=1:size(img_crop,2)%column
       img_crop(row_first(1,j),j,1)=0;%R
       img_crop(row_first(1,j),j,2)=1;%G
       img_crop(row_first(1,j),j,3)=0;%B
   end

 figure(11),imshow(img_crop);
```

Attached I have the original image (left),and the final (right)

---

Why is this happening, what is the error?

Comment: You are just changing `1` pixel in each column, Are you sure that's what you want?

Comment: What is your goal? and give an example for `row_first`.

Comment: I don't quite understand how you are changing the pixels.  You are using `row_first` to access the first dimension (rows), but the second dimension (columns) is varying with the loop index `j`.  Is this what you want?  Also, how is `img_crop` being declared?  Please show more code that sets up your image and leads us to the `for` loop.  Why don't you edit your post and explain how you actually want to edit the pixel values instead?

Comment: So if I understand correctly, do you mean that your entire image stays red even after executing above code? If yes, then the image pixel must be changing to green, but you may not be noticing since its only one pixel. I mean that's rare since entire image is green, but you can double check.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't told us **how** you are defining `img_crop`.  Nevertheless, by looking at your code, my guess is that you are declaring a RGB image, but you are only setting the first **channel** to `img_gauss`.  Declare `img_crop` this way and try your code again:

```
img_crop = cat(3,img_gauss,img_gauss,img_gauss);
```